# LIKE is faster than FULLTEXT search in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `documents` that have around 30 columns, around 3.5 million rows at a size of about 10GB. The most important columns are:

`system_id`, `archive_id`, `content`, `barcodes`, `status` and `notes`.

As you can see this is a multi-tenant application where each tenant is a `system` and references through `system_id`.

I have 2 indexes on this table where the first one is a BTREE and have the columns `system_id`, `archive_id` and `status` in it's index.

The other one is a FULLTEXT index containing the columns `content`, `barcodes` and `notes`.

I have two different tenants that I want to highlight. The first one (Customer A) has `system_id` = 1 and have say 1000 records in the documents table. The second one (Customer B) have `system_id` = 2 and say 400 000 records in this table.

The `LIKE` query for `Customer A` is:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM documents 
WHERE system_id = 1 AND
      CONCAT_WS(' ',content,barcodes,notes) LIKE '%office%' AND
      status = 100
```

The above query will run in about `0.02` seconds. If I run a similar query but with the FULLTEXT search like

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM documents 
WHERE system_id = 1 AND
      MATCH(content,barcodes,notes) AGAINST ('office' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND
      status = 100
```

This operation takes around `4` seconds?! I have read that the FULLTEXT search index should be a lot quicker than LIKE.

If I run the same queries but for Customer B (that has 400 000 records in the documents table) the LIKE search is a little bit slower than FULLTEXT but not with a lot.

- What can the reason for this be?
- Should I go with LIKE or FULLTEXT search in above situation (8GB RAM database server)?

I'm a little bit confused of why my queries with FULLTEXT search is taking so long. The text in content is probably not just words that a normal person would use because it's OCR-read from the document so there will be a lot of different words that might blow up the index?

Comment: fulltext searches are  for searching more than one word, try your search with two or more search values, that are linked with or

Comment: @nbk This is not what I've heard? Fulltext search in MySQL is searching for full words in text? Do not have to be 2 words or linked with or if I'm not misstaken?

Comment: If you only wqant to search for one word, plese use onoly LIKE, Full TeXt is for much mor complicated searches

Comment: Queries are not equivalent - hence the question makes no sense.

Comment: @Akina I know that they are not exactly equivalent but I'm trying to do the same thing. I'm trying to find documents with `office` in the text. I understand the difference and that with FULLTEXT search you can do lots of other operations and complex searches. This hasn't been the question. I wonder why LIKE (which I've heard should be slower) is this much faster than FULLTEXT when performing these two different queries.

Answer (score 2):

The `EXPLAINs` will show that the fast query is using your index on system_id and status, not the LIKE.  It was fast, not because of LIKE, but because of that filtering.

And the slow query decided to use the FULLTEXT index because the Optimizer is too dumb to realize that lots of rows contain "office".

`LIKE`, especially in conjunction with `CONCAT_WS` is *not* faster than `FULLTEXT`.